# React Hook useEffect missing dependency for object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I split my object in the dependency but now eslint is showing warning for missing dependency.

```
const MyComp = () => {
    const data = {name:'ss', age: 1}

    useEffect(() => {

    }, [data.name, data.age])

    return <div>content</div>
}
```

I can't put the entire `data` to avoid unwanted rerendering.

Comment: It's hard for us to help you without knowing what the contents of `useEffect` are. Basically, the rule is: If it's a variable the `useEffect` callback uses, that variable must be in the dependency array. (Exceptions are state setters and other functions you get from the built-in hooks.)

Comment: Maybe it helps to destructure `data` and use these variables inside `useEffect`? Like this: `const {name, age} = data; useEffect(fn, [name, age];)`. Of course `fn` should then use `name` and `age` instead of `data.name` and `data.age`.

Comment: You've shown `data` as a constant. Is it really a state member?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you use `data` within the hook. You've said you can't add `data` itself as the dependency because it would cause too much rendering. That means you need to split `data` up:

```
const MyComp = () => {
    const name ='ss'
    const age = 1

    useEffect(() => {
        // Use `name` and `age` here
    }, [name, age])

    return <div>content</div>
}
```

When using hooks, you generally want to prefer separate state members (I assume `data` is a state member, not really a constant) over using an object state member.

Or another way, as [Michael H pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62230511/react-hook-useeffect-missing-dependency-for-object/62230548#comment110059749_62230511):

```
const MyComp = () => {
    const data = {name: 'ss', age: 1}

    const {name, age} = data // <=========================
    useEffect(() => {
        // Use `name` and `age` (not `data`) here
    }, [name, age])          // <=========================

    return <div>content</div>
}
```